# Multiply a data frame row-by-row

Tags: r, multiplication

Input file:

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=c("w","x","y","z"), 
                  A=c(0,0,0,0),
                  B=c(0,1,0,0), 
                  C=c(1,0,1,0), 
                  D=c(1,1,1,1))

  A B C D
w 0 0 1 1
x 0 1 0 1
y 0 0 1 1
z 0 0 0 1
```

I want to apply an equation i.e. multiply row w to row x to get the pairwise value for w-x pair, as follows:

```
      A B C D
    w 0 0 1 1
X   x 0 1 0 1
--------------
   wx 0 0 0 1
```

to get row-wise analysis for w-x, w-y, w-y, w-z, x-y, x-z, y-z. and generate a new dataframe with 6 columns (two row names followed by the multiplied values).

That's

```
w x 0 0 0 1
w y 0 0 1 1
w z 0 0 0 1
x y 0 0 0 1
x z 0 0 0 1
y z 0 0 0 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the combo names in the resulting object, then we can combine elements of @DWin's and @Owen's Answers to provide a truly vectorised approach to the problem. (You can add the combination names as row names with one extra step at the end.)

First, the data:

```
dat <- read.table(con <- textConnection("  A B C D
w 0 0 1 1
x 0 1 0 1
y 0 0 1 1
z 0 0 0 1
"), header=TRUE)
close(con)
```

Take the `combn()` idea from @DWin's Answer but use it on the *row indices* of `dat`:

```
combs <- combn(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 2)
```

The rows of `combs` now index the rows of `dat` that we want to multiply together:

```
> combs
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4    3    4    4
```

Now we take the idea @Owen showed, namely `dat[i, ] * dat[j, ]` with `i` and `j` being the first and second rows of `combs` respectively. We convert to a matrix with `data.matrix()` as this will be more efficient for large objects, but the code will work with `dat` as a data frame too.

```
mat <- data.matrix(dat)
mat[combs[1,], ] * mat[combs[2,], ]
```

which produces:

```
> mat[combs[1,], ] * mat[combs[2,], ]
  A B C D
w 0 0 0 1
w 0 0 1 1
w 0 0 0 1
x 0 0 0 1
x 0 0 0 1
y 0 0 0 1
```

To see how this works, note that `mat[combs[k,], ]` produces a matrix with various rows repeated in the order specified by the combinations:

```
> mat[combs[1,], ]
  A B C D
w 0 0 1 1
w 0 0 1 1
w 0 0 1 1
x 0 1 0 1
x 0 1 0 1
y 0 0 1 1
> mat[combs[2,], ]
  A B C D
x 0 1 0 1
y 0 0 1 1
z 0 0 0 1
y 0 0 1 1
z 0 0 0 1
z 0 0 0 1
```

To get exactly what the OP posted, we can modify the rownames using a second `combn()` call:

```
> out <- mat[combs[1,], ] * mat[combs[2,], ]
> rownames(out) <- apply(combn(rownames(dat), 2), 2, paste, collapse = "")
> out
   A B C D
wx 0 0 0 1
wy 0 0 1 1
wz 0 0 0 1
xy 0 0 0 1
xz 0 0 0 1
yz 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("  A B C D
+ w 0 0 1 1
+ x 0 1 0 1
+ y 0 0 1 1
+ z 0 0 0 1
+ "), header=TRUE)
> combos <- combn(rn,2)
> combos
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "w"  "w"  "w"  "x"  "x"  "y" 
[2,] "x"  "y"  "z"  "y"  "z"  "z" 

apply(combos,2, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], unlist(dat[x[1],]*dat[x[2],])))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  "w"  "w"  "w"  "x"  "x"  "y" 
  "x"  "y"  "z"  "y"  "z"  "z" 
A "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
B "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
C "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0" 
D "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"
```

So the final solution:

```
t( apply(combos,2, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], unlist(dat[x[1],]*dat[x[2],]))) )
```

If you convert the combos to a dataframe you would also be able to cbindmatrix as type "numeric":

```
 cbind( as.data.frame(t(combos)), 
        t( apply(combos,2, function(x)  
                    unlist(dat[x[1],]*dat[x[2],]))) )

  V1 V2 A B C D
1  w  x 0 0 0 1
2  w  y 0 0 1 1
3  w  z 0 0 0 1
4  x  y 0 0 0 1
5  x  z 0 0 0 1
6  y  z 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply rows, I recommend converting to a matrix:

```
> m = as.matrix(df1)

> m["x", ] * m["y", ]
A B C D 
0 0 0 1
```

The specific result you want you could get with `plyr`,

```
library(plyr)

ldply(1:(nrow(m)-1), function(i)
    ldply((i+1):nrow(m), function(j) {
        a = row.names(m)[[i]]
        b = row.names(m)[[j]]

        do.call(data.frame,
            c(list(a=a, b=b), m[i,] * m[j,])
        )
    })
)
```

Sorry part of that looks a little magical -- data.frames aren't really meant to be "row like". The lines

```
do.call(data.frame,
    c(list(a=a, b=b), m[i,] * m[j,])
)
```

pass in the 6 columns: a and b for the names, concatenated (with `c`) to the multiplied row.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way (I think) using the amazing plyr package

Your data.frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(row.names=c("w","x","y","z"), A=c(0,0,0,0), B=c(0,1,0,0), C=c(1,0,1,0), D=c(1,1,1,1))

YOUR_COMBS<-combn(rownames(df1),2)
```

And your result :)

```
require(plyr) #(version 1.81...in version 1.82 you can take the annoying 'X1' index out... )


     YOUR_RESULTS<-adply(YOUR_COMBS,2,function(x) {
      tmp_row<-data.frame(Comb=paste0(x,collapse = ''),df1[x[1],]*df1[x[2],])
 })
```