# What is the least memory demanding methods to do these steps?

Tags: r, memory

I have posted [a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568246/how-to-do-row-wise-subtraction-and-replace-a-specific-number-with-zero), and got wonderful response from the experts.  However, I am facing another question now, I found the jobs cannot be done in my real data as my starting file (df1) are too large.  I wonder if there are faster method to do the same job without using adply or for loop?

My original questions is listed as below:

Step 1: I have a simplified dataframe like this:

```
df1 = data.frame (B=c(1,0,1), C=c(1,1,0)
  , D=c(1,0,1), E=c(1,1,0), F=c(0,0,1)
  , G=c(0,1,0), H=c(0,0,1), I=c(0,1,0))

  B C D E F G H I
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
3 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Step 2: I want to do row wise subtraction, i.e. (row1 - row2), (row1 - row3) and (row2 - row3)

```
row1-row2    1  0    1  0    0  -1   0  -1
row1-row3    0  1    0  1   -1   0  -1   0
row2-row3   -1  1   -1  1   -1   1  -1   1
```

step 3: replace all -1 to 0

```
row1-row2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
row1-row3   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
row2-row3   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

Could you mind to teach me how to do so in a less memory-demanding approach?

Comment: Also, is your data always binary, i.e. 0 and 1?

Comment: How is this (and the related Q) different from the Q you asked a few weeks ago where the aim was multiplication not subtraction? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297505/multiply-a-data-frame-row-by-row/7298277#7298277

Comment: If you use a memory mapped file, via a package like `bigmemory`, you can use very little RAM and have monstrously big data sets - everything you can fit onto your HD space.

Comment: I repeat after @Andrie: how many rows and how many columns is in your data.frame? Simple `dim(df1)` output.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way I know to do step 2 is to use indices into `df1` for the various pairwise comparisons you want to do. The `combn()` function can be used to generate the set of row-by-row comparisons required. (Using this will be the rate limiting step for *big* data sets.)

For the combinations of row-by-rows operations we want to form:

```
> cmb <- combn(as.numeric(rownames(df1)), 2)
> cmb
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
```

The rows of `cmb` represent the two sets of indices required from `df1` required to form the three rows of your requested output. (The columns, 3, represent the 3 rows in your expected result.)

The next step is to use the two rows of `cmb` to index `df1` and use a standard vectorised operation in R via `-`, e.g.:

```
> (out <- df1[cmb[1,], ] - df1[cmb[2,], ])
     B C  D E  F  G  H  I
1    1 0  1 0  0 -1  0 -1
1.1  0 1  0 1 -1  0 -1  0
2   -1 1 -1 1 -1  1 -1  1
```

Step 3 can now be done, although I am assuming that there can only be `1`, `0`, and `-1` values in the resulting output:

```
> out[out < 0] <- 0
> out
    B C D E F G H I
1   1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1.1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
2   0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Which is consistent with the output you requested.

For big operations, doing this with matrices might be faster overall. So we could do:

```
> mat <- data.matrix(df1)
> cmb <- combn(seq_len(NROW(mat)), 2)
> cmb
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
> out2 <- mat[cmb[1,], ] - mat[cmb[2,], ]
> out2[out2 < 0] <- 0
> out2
     B C D E F G H I
[1,] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
[2,] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
[3,] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

If you need the rownames as you show, then you can easily generate these at the end:

```
> apply(cmb, 2, function(x) paste("row", x[1], "-row", x[2], sep = ""))
[1] "row1-row2" "row1-row3" "row2-row3"
```

which can be used as:

```
> rownames(out) <- apply(cmb, 2, function(x) paste("row", x[1], "-row", x[2], sep = ""))
> out
          B C D E F G H I
row1-row2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
row1-row3 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
row2-row3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the sqldf package or RSQLite directly would allow one to do this with all computations done outside of R so that there would be no intermediate storage required. We illustrate using sqldf.  See the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) for more info.

**Alternative 1** In this approach note that we use `dbname = tempfile()` so that it performs all computations in an external database (which it creates on the fly and automatically deletes) rather than doing it in memory.

```
library(sqldf)
gc()
DF <- sqldf("select x.rowid x, y.rowid y,
    max(x.B - y.B, 0) B, max(x.C - y.C, 0) C, 
    max(x.D - y.D, 0) D, max(x.E - y.E, 0) E,
    max(x.F - y.F, 0) F, max(x.G - y.G, 0) G, 
    max(x.H - y.H, 0) H, max(x.I - y.I, 0) I
    from df1 x, df1 y
    where x.rowid > y.rowid", dbname = tempfile())
```

This would only require that we are able to store `df1` and `DF` in our workspace.

**Alternative 2**. If even that overflows we can write out `df1`, remove it, perform the calculation below and then we would only need sufficient storage to store the result, `DF`.

`read.csv.sql` uses `dbname = tempfile()` by default so in this case we do not need to specify it.

```
write.table(df1, "data.txt", sep = ",", quote = FALSE)
rm(df1)
gc()
DF <- read.csv.sql("data.txt", sql = "select
    x.rowid x, y.rowid y, 
    max(x.B - y.B, 0) B, max(x.C - y.C, 0) C, 
    max(x.D - y.D, 0) D, max(x.E - y.E, 0) E,
    max(x.F - y.F, 0) F, max(x.G - y.G, 0) G, 
    max(x.H - y.H, 0) H, max(x.I - y.I, 0) I
    from file x, file y
    where x.rowid > y.rowid")
```

(Of course, if its really this large then you might have trouble doing any subsequent calculations on it too.)

**Output**. At any rate, both alternatives give the same result shown below.  x and y show which input rows were subtracted.

```
> DF
  x y B C D E F G H I
1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
2 3 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
3 3 2 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

**Note**. Although the question asked for optimizing memory rather than speed if speed were an issue one could add indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Since the data is homogeneous, use a matrix representation. Organize it so that the 'rows' are columns, as

```
m <- t(as.matrix(df1))
mode(m) <- "integer"  # maybe already true?
```

pre-allocate the space for an answer

```
n <- ncol(m) - 1
ans <- matrix(0L, nrow(m), (n+1) * n / 2)
```

We want to compare column `1` to columns `1:n + 1L` (the `1L` treats the number one as an integer value, rather than real). This is `m[,1] - m[, 1:n + 1L]`, using R's recycling. Iterating over columns, with `idx` and `off` helping to keep track of the index of the columns we want to compare to, and the placement columns in the answer

```
off <- 0
for (i in 1:n) {
    idx <- i:n + 1L
    ans[, off + seq_along(idx)] <- m[, i] - m[, idx]
    off <- off + length(idx)
}
```

The final step is

```
ans[ans<0L] <- 0L
```

Maybe there are additional efficiencies from realizing that the truth table under the original operation is 0 unless `m[,1] == 1 & m[, 1:n + 1L] == 0`. Likewise if space were a serious issue then the data might be represented as `mode(m) <- "raw"` and the arithmetic operations replaced with the comparison just suggested, along the lines of:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(df1))
mode(m) <- "raw"

off <- 0
x0 <- as.raw(0); x1 <- as.raw(1)
ans <- matrix(raw(), nrow(m), (n+1) * n / 2)
for (i in 1:n) {
    idx <- i:n + 1L
    updt <- which((m[, i] == x1) & (m[, idx] == x0))
    ans[off + updt] <- x1
    off <- off + length(idx) * nrow(ans)
}
```

Comment: Great answer - might I suggest `mode(m) <- 'integer'` at the top and `ans[ans<0] <- 0L` at the end to keep the result `integer` and save 50% of memory? ...But your idea to use `raw` might be even better although `raw` is awkward to use.

Comment: Thanks Tommy I updated the code as you suggest, and completed a version of the 'raw' solution.